# VSCode Language Extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, tmlanguage

I am building a custom language extension, and am having issues with lineComment in language-configuration.json.  My language, oddly, uses "@@" as a line Comment, and I cannot get this to work.

I have tried @@, @@, and so on.

Any tips?

(Updated from a comment):

This is the entirety of my language-configuration.json:

```
{
     "comments": {
         // single line comment
         "lineComment": "@@"
     },
     // symbols used as brackets
     "brackets": [
         ["{", "}"],
         ["[", "]"],
         ["(", ")"]
     ],
     "autoClosingPairs": [
         ["{", "}"],
         ["[", "]"],
         ["(", ")"]
     ],
     "surroundingPairs": [
         ["{", "}"],
         ["[", "]"],
         ["(", ")"]
     ] }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very similar to the traditional C++ line comment. Here's what I use in my syntax repository:

```
    {
      "name": "comment.line.double-slash",
      "match": "\/\/.*"
    }
```

I guess you tried already:

```
    {
      "name": "comment.line.double-at",
      "match": "\@\@.*"
    }
```

? I'm not sure if you even need to escape the @ sign, since it has no special meaning in JS regular expressions AFAIK.

Comment: I have tried that.  Not sure why it didn't work one of the two ways.

Comment: Then maybe you have a conflicting rule so that this one never comes to match? Try disabling all other rules and just have this comment rule in your language spec. That should then work.

Comment: This is the entirety of my language-configuration.json:

`{
    "comments": {
        // symbol used for single line comment. Remove this entry if your language does not support line comments
        "lineComment": "@@"
    },
    // symbols used as brackets
    "brackets": [
        ["{", "}"],
        ["[", "]"],
        ["(", ")"]
    ],
    "autoClosingPairs": [
        ["{", "}"],
        ["[", "]"],
        ["(", ")"]
    ],
    "surroundingPairs": [
        ["{", "}"],
        ["[", "]"],
        ["(", ")"]
    ]
}`

Comment: However, what I gave you in my answer is not from the language configuration, but the theme file (often .tmTheme is used, but you can also use a json file) [look here](https://github.com/mike-lischke/vscode-antlr4/blob/master/syntaxes/antlr.json).

Comment: Ah, thank you sir.  I don't have a .thTheme file in the structure that Yeoman built out for me, so I am researching how to build one and where to put it in the file structure that exists for my extension.

Comment: I have found this GREAT piece of advice: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/themes-snippets-colorizers#_adding-a-new-color-theme

When I check the TM Scopes with the comment '@@' selected, it tells me 'token type: Other' with 'No theme selector'.  I think that this is teaching me more as I go.